# How to write a conditional in a search query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am searching among documents in a particular district. Documents have various statuses. The aim is to return all documents, except when document's status code is `ABCD` - such documents should only be returned if their ID is greater than 100. I have tried writing multiple queries, including the one below, which returns only the `ABCD` documents with ID greater than 100, and none of the other documents. What is wrong here? How can I get the non-ABCD documents as well?

````
    "_source": true,
    "from": 0,
    "size": 50,
    "sort": [
      {
        "firstStamp": "DESC"
      }
    ],
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "term": {
              "districtId": "3755"
            }
          },
          {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "documentStatus.code.keyword": [
                      "ABCD"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": {
                      "script": {
                        "script": "doc['id'].value > 100"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }```
````

Comment: can u please share your index data, mapping, and expected search result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since you have not added any index mapping, looking at your search
> query data seems to be of [object field data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html). As far as I can
> understand, your aim is to return all documents, except when the
> document's status code is `ABCD` and document with status code `ABCD`
> should only be returned if their ID is greater than 100.

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "id":200,
  "documentStatus":{
    "code":"DEF"
  }
}
{
  "id":200,
  "documentStatus":{
    "code":"ABCD"
  }
}
{
  "id":100,
  "documentStatus":{
    "code":"ABCD"
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "documentStatus.code.keyword": [
                    "ABCD"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": {
                    "script": {
                      "script": "doc['id'].value > 100"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "terms": {
                "documentStatus.code.keyword": [
                  "ABCD"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result:

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64351595",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 2.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": 200,
          "documentStatus": {
            "code": "ABCD"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64351595",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": 200,
          "documentStatus": {
            "code": "DEF"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use must_not in your query if you want to have documents which don't have status code = ABCD. So your query would be some thing like this:

```
    "from": 0,
    "size": 50,
    "sort": [
      {
        "firstStamp": "DESC"
      }
    ],
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "districtId": "3755"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "id": {
              "gt": 100
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "documentStatus.code.keyword": [
              "ABCD"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```